# Is there a way to get kahadb directory size using activemq-admin command line tool?

Tags: apache, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

I am using ActiveMQ 5.10. I want to get kahadb size (persistence store) using activemq-admin tool, is there a way to do it?

Thanks

P.S. I have asked this question at activemq user forum but didn't got a reply and hence posting it on stack overflow, so please don't mark it duplicate.

Link to question that I have asked:
http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Is-there-a-way-to-get-kahadb-size-using-activemq-admin-command-line-tool-tt4687052.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get that information from the activemq-admin script:

```
activemq-admin query  --view StorePercentUsage,StoreLimit --jmxurl service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:port/jmxrmi --jmxuser user --jmxpassword password
```

Just change hostname:port and user/password to your values.  If you have not secured JMX then you may not need the user/password

Comment: This will give in term of percent, so to get exact value is there a way?

Comment: StoreLimit*StorePercentUsage

Comment: thats what I did (ut it is just an approximation)

Answer (score 1):

not through the old console, but the newer [hawtio](http://hawt.io/plugins/activemq/) console does give you access to the store limit (max size) and store percentage used...

otherwise, you can use [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) to access this data OR use [HTTP/REST](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) (via jolokia)...

Comment: can I do it using activemq-active command line tool in any way, actually I need to do it via python script which is used to monitor health of my ActiveMQ Broker>